# The Django's Authenticate method in my login view doesn't work properly. It doesn't even authenticates the users which the admin creates

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**I first created a custom user model by inheriting AbstratctBaseUser:**

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from .manager import FirstManager


#Making custom User model

class MyRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    location_list=[
        ('Solapur', 'Solapur'),
        ('Latur', 'Latur'),
        ('Dhule', 'Dhule'),
        ('Akola', 'Akola'),
        ('Nashik', 'Nashik')
        ]
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=location_list, default='Latur')
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'designation']
    objects=FirstManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**My custom manager:**

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class FirstManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations=True
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required!')
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, location=location, designation=designation, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields)
```

**The Registration form:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyRegistration
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

#Signup form

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2=forms.CharField(label='Confirm', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model=MyRegistration
        fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location', 'designation']
```

**The Registration view in views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('password1')==request.POST.get('password2'):
            try:
                MyRegistration.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username'))
                return render (request, 'account/signup.html', {'error':'This username already exists!'})
            except MyRegistration.DoesNotExist:
                MyRegistration.objects.create_user(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'),
                username=request.POST.get('username'),
                email=request.POST.get('email'),
                location=request.POST.get('location'),
                designation=request.POST.get('designation'),
                password=request.POST.get('password1'))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        fm=MyRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form':fm})

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'account/success.html')
```

**I did not create a login form of my own, instead I manually created the fields in the login template and wrote the view like this:**

```
def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.POST)
            uname = request.POST.get('username')
            upass = request.POST.get('password')
            print(uname, upass)
            user = authenticate(request, username=uname, password=upass)
            if user is not None:
                print(user)
                logs(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully !!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Not validated!')
        else:
            return render(request, 'account/login.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

def home(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'account/home.html', {'Name': request.user})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

**The Login template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'account/images/logo.ico' type='image/x-icon' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'account/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'account/css/style.css' %}">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body class="forbody">

    <div class="container text-end trp" style="margin-top: 2%;">
        <img src="{% static 'account/images/Logo.png' %}" alt="Logo" style="height: 20%; width: 20%;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="container" style="width: 40%; margin-top: 10%;">
        <div class="container" style="width: auto; margin-top: 8%;">
            <div class="container" style="background-color: #696969; height: auto; width: auto; margin-top: 8%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
                        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; width: auto;">
                        <input type="text" name="username" autofocus autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="10" required id="id_username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
                        <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; width: auto;">
                        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required id="id_password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
                        <small style="margin-top: 5px;">To register <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="signuptag">Click Here</a></small>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="{% static 'account/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'account/js/popper.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'account/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And finally, The URLs:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from account import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

I have checked properly that I'm entering the usernames and passwords correctly. What might be the issue here?

Comment: have you added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'some_app.MyRegistration' in your config.py ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It's AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.MyRegistration'.

Comment: Does it pass this? if user is not None

Comment: And the registration works smoothly. The user gets created, but doesn't get authenticated for I don't know what reasons. Can you spot something wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a github repo with the code?

Comment: No. It doesn't. It jumps on the else part. That's the issue. Without the else part it threw ValueError for returning None and not an HTTPRespose.

Comment: Your question: Do you have a github repo with the code?
Answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it fixed but I don't know if it is legit. I set the user active in the create_user function in the manager and it logged the user in instantly. Someone please correct me if that's gonna hurt me later on. Here is the code:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class FirstManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required!')
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(username=username, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, location=location, designation=designation, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(username, email, first_name, last_name, location, designation, password, **extra_fields)
```